# exiting bind('click', function(event) {}) if some condition id fulfilled

Tags: jquery

I need to exit a *bind('click', function(event) {})* block under certain conditions. event.preventDefault() or return false are not helping seemingly. It will be of much help if someone can enlighten me regarding what is happening. Thanks in advance and regards.

Sukalyan

the jquery is as following :

```
$('a').bind('click', function (e) { 

            if (/#enter/.test(this.href)) { //exit bind.click
                e.preventDefault();
                //return false;
            }

            if (/#edit/.test(this.href)) { //exit bind.click
                e.preventDefault();
                //return false;
            }

            $('.content:visible').hide();
            $(this.hash).show();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the event handling code conditionally:

```
$('a').bind('click', function (e) { 

    if (!/#enter/.test(this.href) && !/#edit/.test(this.href)) { 
        $('.content:visible').hide();
        $(this.hash).show();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Vince, thanks for your suggestions. What I found is test(this.href) does not work when I put the '#' before the ID. Otherwise your code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your point so there are 2 ways

1st:  prevent and do actions for all links but not link with href begins with #enter or #edit

```
$('a:not([href^="#enter"]):not([href^="#edit"])').on('click',function(e){
      $('.content:visible').hide();
      $(this.hash).show();
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

2nd: prevent and do action just for links with href begins with #enter or #edit

```
$('a[href^="#enter"], a[href^="#edit"]').on('click',function(e){
          $('.content:visible').hide();
          $(this.hash).show();
          e.preventDefault();
});
```